# Sorting files in a folder using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, directory

I have a code that reads all the files in a folder, paste the file names in a worksheet and output the number of files into a message box.

**Problem:** for some reason, when I run the code, it may get the files in the wrong order, which breaks my calculations (which I do with another sub).

**Question:** Is there a way to guarantee that the files will always be in the correct order?

**What I did so far:** Before the code output the file names, I would like to use some code to sort the files in the folder in a given order, but I cannot find any reference on how to do that.

**Code:**

```
Sub Counter()

Dim path As String, count As Integer, i As Long, var As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Filename As String
Dim FileTypeUserForm As UserForm
Dim x As String

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\*.*"

Filename = Dir(path)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILES").Range("A:A").ClearContents


x = GetValue
If x = "EndProcess" Then Exit Sub


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILES")
i = 0
Do While Filename <> ""
    var = InStr(Filename, x)

    If var <> 0 Then
        i = i + 1
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 1) = Filename
        Filename = Dir()

    Else: Filename = Dir()
    End If

Loop

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

ws.Cells(1, 2) = i

MsgBox i & " : files found in folder"
End Sub


Function GetValue()
With FileTypeUserForm
    .Show
    GetValue = .Tag
End With
Unload FileTypeUserForm
End Function
```

Comment: You could store the results of Dir() in an array, sort this array into a new one and use this array then.

Comment: @R3uK How can I do that? If I just use Dir(path) won't it just give me the location, not the contents? And in that case, if I have array, how can I access it with my current code (which is simply using a string)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a sort instruction when you have put all the filenames in column A

```
range("A1:A" & i).sort key1:=range("A1"),order1:=xlascending,header:=xlno
```